# Set default meeting length on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, duration, defaults

This [appears](http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/answers/how_to_change_the_default_duration_of_new_ical_events) to be the command to set the default meeting length for iCal events:

```
defaults write com.apple.iCal 'Default duration in minutes for new event' X
```

Where X is 30 means that the default meeting length is 30 mins.

My question is - what is the equivalent of this API on iOS? I haven't been able to find it in the API docs - but perhaps I'm not looking in the right place.

Comment: Well it is a question about the API - which you would need to know to start programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible on iOS, at least not system wide. You can provide your own UI in your own app which has a different default length.

Comment: Ok - so you're saying there is no way to change the one that the Calendar app uses.